# Why does an expectation in $nextTick never fail?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I need to use `$nextTick` in order to test some parts of my program. Somehow, it breaks my tests and make them success all the time - even when they **should** fail.

A minimal test sample would look like this:

```
import App from "./App";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";

it("should fail", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App);
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
        expect(1).toBe(3);
        done();
    });
});
```

You can find a sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvpymwnnoj)

If you open the console, you should find the following error messages:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)
```

Why does the test success? Why are the errors ignored? How do I use `$nextTick` properly if note [like so](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a
>   data change, you can use Vue.nextTick(callback) immediately after the
>   data is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been
>   updated.

I can not see any trigger that change DOM in your test. And you missed `done` argument in test callback

For example in the following this is `wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')`

```
it('fetches async when a button is clicked', (done) => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo)
  wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
  wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.value).toBe('value')
    done()
  })
})
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing but I got the same error :

wrapper.vm.getServerInfo();
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.myKeyManager).toBe(null);
      done();
    });